# i didn't found how or is it possible to install MAYA on a 32-bit ubuntu?

Tags: 32-bit, software-installation

i need to know how i can install MAYA (any possible version) on a 32-bit Ubuntu!!.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best suggession i can give is to dual boot your pc. Windows along side ubuntu. Linux is not yet able to replace windows completely, i use ubuntu just because i like it, i have passion to taste different flavour. Thats it.
Windows is developed profesionally, but ubuntu/ linux is not developped that way. Linux is free, so u simplly cant expect everything to be smooth.

Comment: Thanks.well I already have a dual boot (win 7) but i rarely use it.i think i might find the same problem with win 7 32-bit .

Comment: Yes maya i guess only for 64 bit operating system as it requires huge data to process.